# Can White Balance Mode be controlled on starting camera app? (ios)

Tags: ios, avfoundation

Just a question I have been trying to experiment with.  I know that the iphone camera starts with White Balance on continuous (2) in most if not all of the camera apps i have, as found in AVCaptureDevice.h in the AVFoundation framework:

```
enum {
AVCaptureWhiteBalanceModeLocked                     = 0,
AVCaptureWhiteBalanceModeAutoWhiteBalance           = 1,
AVCaptureWhiteBalanceModeContinuousAutoWhiteBalance = 2,
```

};

But is there anyway that I can force it to start with White Balance Mode Locked?
I cannot seem to find where its dictating this condition.

I've tried including it in my capture Session here:

```
// Create session (use default AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh)
AVCaptureSession *newCaptureSession = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
[newCaptureSession beginConfiguration];

AVCaptureDevice *device = [self cameraWithPosition:AVCaptureDevicePositionBack];
if ([device isWhiteBalanceModeSupported: AVCaptureWhiteBalanceModeLocked]) {
    if ([device lockForConfiguration:nil]) {
        [device setWhiteBalanceMode:AVCaptureWhiteBalanceModeLocked];
        [device unlockForConfiguration];
    }
}
[newCaptureSession commitConfiguration];
```

...but to no avail.    It's still auto white balancing upon opening the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When setting up your capture session:

```
 AVCaptureDevice *device = [self cameraWithPosition:AVCaptureDevicePositionBack];
 if ([device isWhiteBalanceModeSupported: AVCaptureWhiteBalanceModeLocked]) {
        if ([device lockForConfiguration:nil]) {
             [device setWhiteBalanceMode:AVCaptureWhiteBalanceModeLocked];
             [device unlockForConfiguration];
        }
 }
```

Comment: Edited code.  Tried this method but still not working.  I can assign it to a gesture and it works, but so far its not starting with white balance locked.

Comment: It works, honest. Try putting it later in your setup (even at the very end of `viewDidLoad`)...

Comment: Well, I think I'll have to work the code a bit.  I transferred it as is to `viewDidLoad` and ran into errors. Sorry...obj-c isn't my strong point.

Comment: You'll possibly need to get `AVCaptureDevice *device` from a rather more abstract location, depending on how your capture session is configured. Something like `AVCaptureDevice *device = [[captureManager videoInput] device];` may work, if you're (say) working through an `AVCamCaptureManager`  called 'captureManager';

Comment: Exactly what I was missing.  Thanks sir!

Comment: For rear camera it is working fine. But not working for front camera . Any thing I have to change in the code?

Comment: Nothing obvious. Are you switching from rear to front after setting the parameters, perhaps?